# How to access temporary access key and secret key for node js application deployed on EC2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My Node Js application is deployed on EC2 and wanted to use S3 bucket with temporary credentials .
 `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');`
`const s3 new AWS.S3();`

How should I generate temporary access key and secret key in Node js for accessing S3 .
Any help will be appreciated
Kindly give the code for javascript.

Comment: What you have is fine for the code, you will just need to attach an IAM instance profile to the ec2 instance and the SDK will use those credentials automatically.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html